# How to update dataframes with PRAW (Reddit) and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes stored in a dictionary ('df_dict'). Each dataframe has 100 rows. For each row I need to add the columns ('new_score', 'new_num_comments', 'upvote_ratio') with the current data from Reddit. I am using PRAW to access the Reddit API.

Since it takes so long to update each row sequentially, i am trying to use multithreading to get the data. So I take a dataframe with 100 rows, start a thread for each and spawn an instance of PRAW for each thread.

Somehow my code seems to work and update the rows, but it takes way too long - awefully long. No difference to updating it sequentially. It takes almost **11.4 seconds** to to update one row with my "multithreading" attempt. While it takes 0.2 seconds if I do this sequentially. What am I doing wrong???

Here is my code. I tried to cut out as much as I could and obviously redacted my credentials:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import praw

# Dataframes are stored in df_dict

mutex = Lock()

threads = []

class ReqThread (Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, index, row):                                
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.threadID = threadID 
        self.index = index
        self.row = row

    def run(self): 
        print("Starting %s" % self.threadID)
        for row in self.row:
            worker(index=self.index, row=self.row)
        print("Exiting %s" % self.threadID) 
        
        
def make_reddit():
    return praw.Reddit(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, username=username, password=password, user_agent=user_agent)
        
def worker(index, row):
    global df
    print('Request-ID: %s' % row['id'])
    reddit = make_reddit()
    submission = reddit.submission(row['id'])
    mutex.acquire() 
    df.at[index, 'new_score'] = submission.score
    df.at[index, 'upvote_ratio'] = submission.upvote_ratio
    df.at[index, 'new_num_comments'] = submission.num_comments
    mutex.release()

for i in df_dict:
    df = df_dict[i]
     
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        t = ReqThread(threadID=index, index=index, row=row)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
        
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    df.to_csv('u_{i}.csv'.format(i=i))
```

EDIT: Calculated again how much my "multithreading" takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be running into is the Python Threading catch.

**Why are these 'threads' slower?**
Despite what it may seem like Python threads are *not* actual threads, the [_thread](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/_thread.html#module-_thread) and [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html) module use OS threads which are great for IO-bound concurrency but less so for CPU-bound tasks, this comes down to Python and the [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) (Global Interpreter Lock) to keep everything threadsafe.
Because you don't get the advantage of multiple cores you're only going to get the overhead of balancing multiple OS threads around.

**So how do I do multi-core processing in Python?**
To get around the GIL issue python makes use of subprocesses to essentially balance the load and make use of multiple cores, modules like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) make use of the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) module internally, You can try this for yourself if you make a process pool of 4 workers and start them, notice how it spawns 4 python processes as well?

**Important things to note**

- Threading Modules in python are actually OS thread systems normally.
- The GIL limits a lot of parallel processing in python.
- IPC can be much harder because you do *not* get the ability to free pass variables across the processes. See [MultiProcessing's Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) for more info.